# What does this mean in JMeter load? 100 in13.2s= 7.4/s

Tags: jmeter

I have checked for load 100 and got result 100 in13.2/s= 7.4/s.

So what is the meaning of 100 in 13.2/s = 7.4/s?

Answer (score 2):

It means the **Number of Executed Samples or Requests** are **100**. **Test duration** is **13.2 seconds** and **Throughput** is **7.4/s**. So your application handled average **7.4 requests per second** during those **13.2** seconds. From that test, the total number of requests are **100**.

**Throughput** is calculated as **requests/unit of time**. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any **intervals between samples**, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
The formula is: **Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time)**.

In fact, there's been a mistake in the question: it should be **"100 in 13.2s"** not **"100 in 13.2/s"**  !!

For further detail, go through Apache JMeter User Manual: [Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) & [Elemants of a Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html).